# How to use traefik as a proxy for LDAP

Tags: ldap, traefik

I am running traefik as a reverse-proxy in my kubernetes cluster to route web traefik form public internet domains. But now I have the reverse problem. Some of my PODs need ot access an external LDAP server. This LDAP server is protected by IP-Address. As I can not foresee on which nodes my pods are scheduled and as I want to avoid to list all possible IP addresses from my cluster in the LDAP server, I wonder if I can use traefik in a reverse configuration. So that all my pods send ldap requests to the traefik instance and traefik connects to the external server (with one address from my master node)

```
->POD sends LDAP request ---> traefik ---> connect external LDAP
```

Is this possible and can someone give a short configuration example?